# bootstrap 3.3.7 will not load with Angular 7.2.0 project

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular7

My Angular project was working fine with Bootstrap 3.3.7 (required for my project) up until I deployed. Bootstrap wasn't being recognized so I went back to adjust some files in my project and now Bootstrap won't work in my local environment anymore. I've been scratching my head over this for two days now and can't seem to find the solution.

```html
 
My angular.json

{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "/",
  "projects": {
    "public": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "public/src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "public/dist/public",
            "index": "public/src/index.html",
            "main": "public/src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "public/src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "public/src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "public/src/favicon.ico",
              "public/src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "public/src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "public/src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "public:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "public:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "public:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "public/src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "public/src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "public/src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "public/src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "public/src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "public/src/favicon.ico",
              "public/src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "public/src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "public/src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "public-e2e": {
      "root": "public/e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "public/e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "public:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "public:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "public/e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "/"
}
```

```html
My package.json


{
  "name": "portfolio",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "ng build --aot -prod"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "7.2.0",
    "@angular/cli": "7.1.4",
    "@angular/common": "7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "7.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "7.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "typescript": "3.2.2",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^3.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/language-service": "7.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "enhanced-resolve": "^3.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.11.0",
    "npm": "3.10.10"
  }
}
```

```html
My dist/publix/index.html

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to localize the bootstrap classes instead of a CDN

Comment: Installing it locally and then adjusting my angular.json "styles" worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I installed bootstrap locally and had to adjust my "styles" in angular.json to point to the correct directory.

```html
            "styles": [
              "public/src/styles.css",
              "./bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
```